# How to access this Html element in FireWatir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, firewatir

<
div id="host-a-meeting"/  >

**How to access the above in Watir.**

Comment: i got the answer.....

ie.div(:id,"host-a-meeting").click          is the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.div(:id,"host-a-meeting").flash
```

replace .flash with whatever method is needed to 'access' the item (click, firevent, etc)